# Generating unbiased numbers with a biased six sided die?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy

Eve takes a fair six-sided die and adds some heavy paint to the side of the die with the 6 on it. This results in a biased die that rolls a 6 with probability 2/7, and each other number (1-5) with probability 1/7.

If Alice learns that the die is loaded in this way, only has this die, and must generate 20 fair/unbiased random numbers between 1 and 6, what procedure can I propose that she can use to generate these fair numbers with this unfair die and computing how many times (exact or on expectation) Alice will have to roll the tampered die to conduct this procedure.

Comment: On a tangent here, but wouldn't making the side with the 6 heavy cause the 6 to be less likely and the 1 more likely?

Comment: How do you define "unbiased"? Anyways, what have you tried in solving this for your self? This site is not a free (homework) question answering service. We expect you to do you due diligence.

Comment: unbiased means the probability of getting each side of the die is equal.

Comment: Does Alice know exact odds for each side ? The solution is very dependent on that.

Comment: Yes alice knows the odds. can you come up with a procedure which she can generate fair numbers with the unfair die and also how many times to compute it

Comment: I'm going with the no-tech solution, scratch the paint off. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about general mathematics without any specific cryptographic elements. Such questions are off-topic here, but may be asked on [math.SE]. (Mind you, they don't tend to like "do my homework for me" questions there, either.)

Comment: If Alice doesn't know the odds then she could also adapt the good old low-tech (but extremely clever) "unfair coin" technique, which might not be optimal but is easy to understand and thus probably more useful in real life with actual dice when two parties are trying to reliably use a biased die to carry out some kind of business. The unfair coin technique: roll twice, then HH -> rethrow, TT -> rethrow, HT -> output 0, TH -> output 1. I'm sure a variant could be devised for six-sided dice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each biased die result has >2.52 bits of [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition). Each unbiased die result has <2.59. So 21 biased rolls have more entropy than 20 unbiased ones.

Alice can concatenate 21 biased results into $r$ and use $r_i = H(s||r||i) \bmod 6$ as the unbiased results, where $H$ is a hash function like SHA-256 and $s$ is a unique salt she decides just before rolling.

(If Alice wants to cheat, she must use >$2^{52}$ work to find an $s$ with biased outputs. If this is insufficient, roll more dice or decide $s$ in a way that does not allow this.)

Comment: Two nice things about this answer: it is not too sensitive to a variation in the bias; and it is on-topic on CSE! $\;$ However if Alice can't choose $s$ at random (which is why she wants to throw a dice in the first place) and $s$ can be predicted by Eve, then Eve can have _some_ advantage, including with significantly less than $2^{52}$ work (by betting on the most likely outcome for the most likely $2^{40}$ values of $r$)

Comment: @fgrieu, true, if $s$ cannot be kept secret and the results should, then anyone knowing $s$ can make some predictions after the fact. To avoid that you'd need significantly more input entropy than the 21 rolls I suggest. Secure application of this procedure depends on the attack model.

Comment: I think your $r_i$ is biased. Assume the least significant three bits of the SHA-256 output are unbiased, so they take $x\in[0;7]$ with equal probability. You'll experience the lower values in the range more often than the higher ones as $6\equiv0\pmod6$, $7\equiv1\pmod6$, so the probability for a 0 or a 1 to occur are 2/8 whereas the probability to hit a 2,3,4,5 are 1/8. Certainly not unbiased.

Comment: @SEJPM, I did not suggest taking the least significant bits modulo 6, but the whole output modulo 6. The probability of 0,1,2,3 is $1/2^{256}$ higher than that of 4,5. I.e. they are equally probable in cryptographic uses. (Assuming SHA-256 is PRF.)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is that Alice repeats until 20 values have been output:

- throw the dice
- if the dice gave other than a 6, output what it gave;
- else throw the dice until it gives other than 1, then output 6 if the dice last gave 5 or 6 (otherwise, output nothing).

---

Proof of correctness: at each outer loop, values 1 to 5 are output with odds $1\over7$ each; when in an outer loop we reach the last step (which has odds $2\over7$) we output 6 with dependent odds ${1+2\over6}={1\over2}$, thus overall odds $1\over7$; thus all six outcomes have equal odds.

When the last step is reached, we enter a loop that terminates with odds $6\over7$ after each extra throw, thus requires an average $7\over6$ throws. Thus in the outer loop there's $1$ dice throw with odds $5\over7$, and an average of $13\over6$ dice throws with odds $2\over7$, thus an average of $4\over3$ dice throws. A loop outputs a value with odds $6\over7$, thus we need an average of $14\over9$ dice throws to generate a value. Thus we generate $20$ values with an expected ${280\over9}\approx31.11$ dice throws.

---

There here are solutions requiring significantly less dice throws on average, including using [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding), which minimizes the average number of throws and will often do with 20 or 21 throws. There is no exact solution requiring a bounded number of throws.

---

In practice, Alice does not know the exact odds of each throw outcome; and the values in the problem statement are unrealistic: if a fair dice gets loaded toward 6, then the opposite side 1 will have its odds lower than that of the other four sides.

Under the assumption that loaded dice throws are independent, it is still possible to simulate an exactly fair dice, but that requires a lot more throws. A practical solution may use hashing, as [suggested by Otus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29633/555), and estimating the actual entropy of the dice from the throws.

Comment: On the last step, I think you could make it clearer that you are suggesting that there can be no output from following all steps (i.e. there is a 1 in 7 chance of no output from a run through the loop, just re-starting instead).

Comment: To get a bounded number of throws per output-or-lack-thereof, the "until it gives other than 1" step can be moved to the beginning and then have its number of repeats limited. $\:$ (In fact, even without the "repeats limited" part, that would also stop timing attacks.) $\;\;\;\;$